# Error in fixture.before hook TypeError: t.maximizeWindow is not a function TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to do some tests on a website which the tasks come after login. So I created a role for login and call it in beforeEach method. When running tests, the login function happens before every test. But I didn't want to happen that and then I moved the role and maximize window function into the before method. Now it gives an error

`Error in fixture.before hook TypeError: t.maximizeWindow is not a function`
Even if I removed the maximizeWindow function and then run, it shows error
`Error in fixture.before hook TypeError: t.useRole is not a function`
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `t.maximizeWindow` and other `t` methods inside the `before` fixture. The `before` and `after` fixture hooks run before or after the content of the fixture. They cannot access the browser.
Please take a look at the https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/advanced-guides/hooks#fixture-hooks article for more details

Comment: Could you please suggest a method to make the scenario work? Because I don't want to see the browser maximize and login to the system at each test in the same fixture.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use roles for every test in fixture you can simply add the `t.useRole` method inside the test body without any hooks.

Please also note that when you are using the Roles mechanism in the `beforeEach` hook, the login process runs only for the first time. For the remaining tests you will be automatically logged in.

Comment: Actually, I was using a role in the `beforeEach` method. But it runs before each test in the fixture

Comment: There is another way to implement your scenario. To speed up the login process, you can use the Roles functionality:

https://testcafe.io/documentation/402845/guides/advanced-guides/authentication#user-roles